# How can i access the /var/www folder from VM instance (SSH console) in Google Cloud?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, repository

i'm asking for help on an issue I've been having while getting some VM instances/servers back online. the problem is that a person who was working before at our company, set up the VM instances before, left us some documentation, where it ask us to Go to Google Cloud -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances and find 2 VM instances called "gap-mongo" and "gap-node".

When we went into Compute Engine -> VM Instances, nothing was there (seems like the instances got removed or moved somewhere else, but we can't see it in our VM instance list), So we decided to start creating a new the 2 VM instances ("gap-mongo" and "gap-node") from scratch and follow the documentation provided.

I got to a stage where i need to reference some repositories that according to the documentation, lives in "root@gap-node:/var/www#" folder, but i have not been able to access it, as i tried by just using cd var/www command, and it told me the folder didn't exist, so i as soon as i saw that, i just decided  to use the mkdir command on the prompt to create the /var/www destination.

However the result i got, is this path "root@gap-node:~/var/www#" and not this one "root@gap-node:/var/www#". so i believe because of that is that i'm not being able to execute the next steps on the documentation, which are using 3 "git remote -v". And I'm not being able to use the commands, because when i use them it displays error: "bash: git: command not found"

I have the theory that the issue is related to the "~" symbol difference on the commands, as according to the documentation provided, we would only need to execute the "root@gap-node:/var/www# git remote -v" commands.

I'm not really sure what i'm missing, so i decided to post this, in order to get some help from you guys, as apparently Technical support for GCP needs to be paid and is not available for my user.

Comment: There is just too much to explain what you did wrong, I'd recommend a basic linux course.

Comment: You really should have someone in your project that at least understands the basics. The mystical `~` means that you've created the directory under your home dir, not in the root (which is `/`). And you seem to be missing git too.